# Are there any ways to set particularly iPhone 6s when debugging in React Native using VSCode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my app, and the React Native Tools extension automatically opens my app in iPhone X, because of weakness of my mac mini, I've been looking for a way to change the device but there's nothing. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I use command line to specify the simulator.

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"
```

Comment: I knew that, bro. But I meant how to select iPhone 6s when debug in vscode, not about how to run normally the project in iPhone 6s